# How to port a Ubuntu C++ library to MinGW?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, mingw, uuid

In Ubuntu, there is a package called `uuid-dev`. To install and use it, I just need to run `apt-get install uuid-dev`. However, in MinGW, I couldn't install this package using `mingw-get install`.

May I know what are the basic steps to port a C++ application/library from Ubuntu to MinGW?

Answer (score 0):

It might already support compilation under MinGW.  Generally you would download the source, unpack them and run `./configure` and see what happens.

Give that a try and get back to me.